# PHP - return pdf from database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdf

I am having some troubles to return PDF data to the browser, Chrome keeps saying that `Failed to load PDF document`. The whole project is build in laravel.

This is what I got so far.

Logging in to FTP server to fetch document from the fileserver.

```
public function download()
{
    ob_start();
    $result = ftp_get($this->connection, "php://output", $this->ftp_filePath.$this->ftp_fileName, FTP_BINARY);
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $data;
}
```

Saving it to the database

```
DB::Table("CD_documents")->insert(array('name' => $fileName, 'type' => $type, 'content' => $content));
```

Then there is another function to read the pdf from the database

```
$document = MODELNAME::returnDocument(50);

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($document->content));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$document->name.'"');
header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

exit($document->content);
```

How do I get the document to be correctly loaded in chrome?

Comment: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en-GB

Comment: @RiggsFolly , the problem aint that chrome isn't opening the file. The problemen is that Chrome cant open the file.

Comment: Try setting your content type to `text/plain` - see if your system is dropping any HTML around your PDF content

Comment: Also try echoing `$document->content` instead of outputting it through `exit`

Comment: @Scoots , I dont see any other HTML content. Does it need to be base64 encoded?

Comment: @mulquin that doesn't make any difference. Could it be that php7.1 does some encoding to the data?

Comment: Sidenote: You can stream data directly to the database using [PDO Large Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lobs.php)

Comment: Why you are storing the PDF to the database? Another approach: Get the pdf from the server, save it to the filesystem and store the path to the database.

Comment: Then you had better shwo us how you stored the PDF into the database in the first place. Likely as not that is not working correct and might well be corrupting the pdf in the process

Comment: @konafets , the problem is that I need to return the pdf file trough an API. I thing I'm going for your approach.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I completely agree with you on that one. I need to send the pdf to another app using an api. How could I do that?